# Passing arguments when initalizing instance of a custom class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning kivy to developp a small app and I have issues with the custom classes. I want to create a custom type of button to define three nice lookings buttons, but I keep getting an error when trying to call my custom class with "arguments".

Here is my code :
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.core.window import Window 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition

Builder.load_file('minimal.kv')
Window.size = (250,450)

class HomeScreen(Screen) : 
    pass

screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
screen_manager.add_widget(HomeScreen(name ="home_screen"))

class MyMinApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    MyMinApp().run()
```

and my kv file is :

minimal.kv

```
<HomeScreen>
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'  
        Mission:
            label_text : 'text1'
                
<Mission@Widget>
    Label:
        id: label_widget
        text: root.label_text
```

the behavior I would expect is the that my Label goes to its root ('HomeScreen') and retrieves the argument 'label_text' which should equal 'text1' but instead it issues the error

`AttributeError: 'Mission' object has no attribute 'label_text'`

can someone please suggest a solution ?

(This ran on python 3.11.5 with kivy 2.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your definition of `Mission` does not provide for a `label_text` attribute. Just add that attribute to your `Mission` definition:

```
<Mission@Widget>
    label_text: ''
    Label:
        id: label_widget
        text: root.label_text
```